# PHP connection with login

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following problem,

When I connect a user at my database, he doesn't remember the login.
Indeed, I want to show the name of the member connected in my web page.

My code:

config.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root','aragorn11') or die ("erreur de connexion");
mysql_select_db('biblio',$connect) or die ("erreur de connexion base");
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["login"])){
    $connected=1;
    $login=$_SESSION["login"];
}
?>
```

And member.php

```
<?php 
include ("config.php"); 
include ("session.php"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Adherents_Connectés</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="accueil.css" />
   </head>
   <body>   

<?php
  echo "<h4>Welcome : $login</h4>\n";
?>

    <h4> <a href = "index.html"> Déconnexion </a> <br/> </h4>


    <p> Liste des actions possibles pour un adherent de la bibliothèque est :
    <ul>
    <a href = "liste_dispo_adherents.php" > Consulter la liste des livres disponibles </a> 
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <a href = "emprunt.php" > Emprunter un livre </a> 
    </ul>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Read this => http://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/

Answer (score 2):

The code you're showing us right now never assigns a value to `$_SESSION["login"]` so it's never set, therefor `$login` will never have a value.

And, oh, [don't use mysql_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: @Bulk More strange things have happened, although you're probably right in this case, I removed the unrelated part.

Comment: Deleted my comment then as it has no context now :) FWIW I think you've got the right answer.